# How to extract information from a text with supervised classification?

Tags: r, machine-learning, text-mining, prediction, information-extraction

I try to make my question clearer and I apologize if I use not correct terms.

I have N text documents of the following form

> "The best number is 200 because [...]"
>
> "I like 250 more than 120 [...]"
>
> "[...]300 is my favourite number"
>
> "Nothing is better than 450[...]"
> etc.

Given this new document:

> "The top of the tops is 125[...]"

How can I extract the information "125"?

I pre-process the text in order to reduce the dimension of the documents from 50 pages to 2-5 sentences by using regexp. I don't do any other operations on the text

Please note that Regexp should not be very useful, since it's quite hard to find a regular pattern and I will have to deal with lots of different kind of information (not only numbers!)

I thought that a machine learning approach would have been useful, so I assigned a value to my N documents (i.e. "200","250","300","450") and I tried to predict the value of "125" with SVM,MAXENT Algorithm from RTextTools packages, but with poor result.

Is my machine learning approach correct and how could I improve my information extraction methodology?

Thanks

Comment: Hi! What kind of preprocessing you perform on your text? Do ou split it into characters or words? Do you tokenize source text strings anyhow? In general, what you use as input into ML algorithms - because raw texts as single strings will not work at all. Please include it into question as well as some specific examples.

Comment: I modified specified the example and added information about text pre-processing

Comment: I'm sorry, why can't you use a regular expression that just captures numbers? I feel like I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would like to extract numbers from every document. Regex is the way to do it. You can try the `rebus` package as provides a more human readable code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a vector `vec` defined as follows:

```
vec <- c("The best number is 200 because [...]",
          "I like 250 more than 120 [...]",
          "[...]300 is my favourite number",
          "Nothing is better than 450[...]",
          "The top of the tops is 125[...]")
```

You can extract all integers using `str_extract_all` from `stringr` package and build regex from `rebus` package:

```
library(rebus)
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(vec, pattern = one_or_more(DGT), simplify = TRUE)
#      [,1]  [,2] 
# [1,] "200" ""   
# [2,] "250" "120"
# [3,] "300" ""   
# [4,] "450" ""   
# [5,] "125" ""
```